# Homomorphism and Monomodrphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

The number of homomorphism from " group of integers under addition modulo n" to "group of integers under addition"1  i.e from Zn to (Z,+) is 1. So it must be trivial homomorphism. I want to ask total number of  injective homomorphism (i.e monomorphism) from Zn to (Z,+) group ?
I can understand if n =2 or n >2 then we get zero monomorphism . But what about n =1 ? 
Where n = order of group Zn.

Comment: The group $Z_1$ has $1$ element, so it's the trivial group, hence the only homomorphism from $Z_1$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is the zero homomorphism, which is the same answer as for $Z_n$, for any positive integer $n$. For $n = 1$, the zero homomorphism is injective.

Comment: So we can conclude that the number of injective homomorphism from Zn to Z =0 if n >1 and otherwise for n=1 ,we get 1

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$